# How to make link return to its normal (not active) state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The idea was simple:

1. change li background color on hover to one color

   ```
   ul#menu li a:hover {...}
   ```
2. change it on mouse press to the other color

   ```
   ul#menu li a:active {...}
   ```
3. return the color to the original (normal) if the link is neither hover nor pressed

The problem appeared to be that, if user rejected his intention and let the mouse up away from the link, the back color stayed as if it had been pressed (i.e. `a:active`).

So it looks like the link gets "active" state and stays in it even after user releases mouse button.

**EDIT**

This is what I came up with the help of posters, who tried to answer this question: please, compare these fiddles:

1. [Fiddle - working as desired](http://jsfiddle.net/4PCLd/)
2. [Fiddle - working as in real application](http://jsfiddle.net/RPRaZ/)

The difference is that the desired fiddle has no `href`. As soon as `href` is added, the link starts behaving as **not** desired. Both of them use:

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#FF0000;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

while

1. `<a>LINK</a>`
2. `<a href="default.asp" target="_blank">LINK</a>`

Surely I have `href` set in my html, so how can I achieve Fiddle #1 behaviour?

So, it looks like it is impossible to do with html and css only. Could there be any workaround using java script?

Comment: Difference that without href hash black font because rule a:link works with href tag.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried it and all work as charm, you need rule for visited links too and set it as default unvisited link

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4PCLd/)

Comment: +1: Though I see your fiddle work as I need, I can't make my example work as well...I'll keep trying

Comment: Maybe you missed some rule in your css, try to build it from zero step by step

Comment: Thanks! Exactly those four rules do present. Nice piece of advice, I'll try to.

Comment: I've found out why it didn't work, or rather why your fiddle worked: as soon as a `href` is added, the link stops working as desired: http://jsfiddle.net/RPRaZ/

Comment: Sorry, but how can I improve the "non-working" fiddle to make it work as the original one, posted by you?

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your requirement I credited a jsfiddle.

Please check the **DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/saorabhkr/Pzuwb/

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, Now your updated answers seems fine me :)